# Правильный подход к выполнению POST запросы на Adnroid

Tags: android, retrofit, rxjava, room

Есть связка Retrofit, Room, Rx. У меня есть сервак с api и локальная база. С приемом данных со всех мест и с их синхронизацией я вопрос решил. Вот теперь новый вопрос, как сделать post запрос с обновленными данными?

Допустим получилось так, что сервер был недоступен и новые данные мы положили в локальную базу. Потом выключили приложение, или свернули, вернулись, и отправили, как и всегда в таком случае, get запрос на получение данных с сервера. Получили старые данные и перезаписали локальную базу. Таким образом потеряли все новые данные.

Есть ли какое-то красивое решение данной проблемы, или придется делать специальную флаговую переменную для определения наличия не синхронизированных данных?

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос сложный и общий. При наличии оффлайн хранилища всегда встает вопрос выбора стратегии целостности данных на сервере. Кто прав, то кто последним поменял или кто последним отправил?
Исходя из ответа на этот вопрос, решения на клиенте могут различаться.

**Нам важна хронология изменений данных.**
Тогда на клиенте надо хранить время последней синхронизации с сервером. Локальные изменения хранить как последовательность с указанием времени каждого изменения. Соответственно на сервер отправлять изменения тоже с указанием времени изменения.

**Нам главное просто отправить.**
Пример: однопользовательские данные, либо меняются очень редко.
Тогда на клиенте храним просто флаг, что данные изменились и отправляем их при первой возможности и только потом запрашиваем обновление с сервера.

**Возможен и смешанный вариант.**
Когда на клиенте храним только последний вариант с указанием времени изменения.

Comment: Спасибо. Мне больше подходит второй вариант, но опять же возникает вопросы реализации. Есть ли какие то интересные варианты реализации, будь то RxJava или же создать сервис для постоянной переотправки данных в случае отсутствия ответа от сервера. Хотелось бы посмотреть на чей то опыт реализации или на статьи, чтобы не топать по граблям, а выбрать наиболее оптимальный вариант

Comment: На сегодняшний момент я бы в вашем случае посмотрел WorkManager из JetPack, очень много интересного о нем на последнем IO рассказывали.
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/

Comment: Спасибо большое, сейчас буду знакомится с ним